# Как вывести ноль перед числом. С++

Tags: c++

```
using namespace std;
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
int main()
{
    int h,m,n,s,a,b,c,k,k1,k2,abc;
    cin>>abc;
    a=(abc/3600)%24;
    b=(abc/60)%60%60;
    c=(abc%60)%60;
    cout<<a<<":"<<b<<":"<<c;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Прежде чем задать вопрос, убедитесь, что вы выполнили тщательный поиск ответа. Поделитесь результатом вашего поиска и расскажите, что вы нашли и почему найденные ответы вас не устроили. Это продемонстрирует вашу способность думать самостоятельно, поможет избежать повторяющихся очевидных ответов и, самое важное, увеличит шансы на получение точного ответа!](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714515/how-can-i-pad-an-int-with-leading-zeros-when-using-cout-operator

Comment: Уже это делал, я не могу понять как здесь при числе например 2 нужно вывести 02

Answer (score 3):

Через `std::setfill('0')` задаём заполнитель, через `std::setw(N)` задаём ширину выводимого числа. Всё что не занято самим числом будет заполнено символом-заполнителем.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    int i = 42;
    std::cout << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(8) << i << "\n";
}
```

Результат:

> ```
> 00000042
> ```